# Getting Forbidden error when saving pages with PHP

Tags: php, tinymce, http-status-code-403

I built a CMS that uses TinyMCE as its editor.

I have PHP protected

```
    protect: [
        // Protect php code
        /<\?php.*?\?>/g,
        /<\?.*?\?>/g,
    ]
```

but for some reason it throws forbidden on submit (only on pages with PHP.)

I'm using an absolute URL in my form `action`, but it's still throwing the 403 (and gives me the relative path in the error)

I wonder if it's server side, as **it works locally** just fine, but not on the live server.

Comment: I have no clue about TinyMCE but do you really have to protect these tags? Sounds really dangerous..

Comment: What is the server setup? Is there perhaps something like mod-security installed? (Which can throw 403 error when things that look like code-injection attacks are submitted) -- As possible solution, you could try encoding it clientside (say base64) before submitting.

Comment: I think I'll try to find a different way of doing this. Maybe just having it set the existing PHP aside and re-attach later. I'll try encoding the data and see if it helps. This particular host is fairly strict/older setup. Thanks [*btw, the only PHP on pages is `include`]